# Excel VBA - PublishToPBI method

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want to publish Excel data to Power BI from within a VBA macro. To do this, I am using the following command:

Activeworkbook.PublishtoPBI

Unfortunately, the macro code doesn’t publish the data to Power BI, although I have Power BI installed on my machine and am a BI Pro user. The manual way of publishing to Power BI (using File —-> options—->Publish) works though. Also, the same code works on my other machine without any problems.

What can be wrong? I also notice that the 'publishtopbi' function is not available as an Excel vba function on my current machine (it's available on my other machine though!). How do I add/insert this function? Thanks.

Regards,

GS

Answer (score 0):

The PublishToPBI does not publish a Power BI Report or Dashboard, it saves the Excel file in the Workbooks section in your Power BI Service, so that you can use it to generate dashboards.
You can find it at the following link: 
https://app.powerbi.com/groups/me/list/workbooks

Although, there is also a way to **direcly Publish Charts/Tables to Power BI from Excel** using [PowerBI Publisher for Excel](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/publisher-for-excel). 
Please check out the following video to see how it works: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xl76Keep5lw

Comment: thanks for your reply, I will check the PowerBI Publisher. I am using the PublishToPBI function to publish Excel tables directly to the dataset in the chosen PowerBI workspace. The function is available on one of my machines but not on the other. Also, there is unfortunately not much information available on the microsoft website regarding the same.